# square the numbers in lists in dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, math

I have a dictionary created like:

```
di = {
    "R": [{7, 9}, {5, 8}], 
    "N": [{6, 9}, {8, 8}], 
    "L": [{7, 9}, {5, 0}], 
    "P": [{0, 9}, {7, 8}]
}
```

I want to square `dic["R"]` numbers so the end result would be `{49, 81}, {25, 64}`.

So far I have:

```
for i in dic['R']:
   squared = [j ** 2 for j in i]
```

but it only returns the second list.

Comment: It gives you the last assigned value of squared, the former is overwritten

Comment: Do you understand, that `{8, 8}` is a `set` and contains only one value `{8}`?

Answer (score 2):

Note that these are not lists of ints, or lists of lists of ints, they are lists of sets of ints:

```
>>> di = {
...     "R": [{7, 9}, {5, 8}],
...     "N": [{6, 9}, {8, 8}],
...     "L": [{7, 9}, {5, 0}],
...     "P": [{0, 9}, {7, 8}]
... }
>>> di["R"] = [{i ** 2 for i in s} for s in di["R"]]
>>> di
{'R': [{81, 49}, {64, 25}], 'N': [{9, 6}, {8}], 'L': [{9, 7}, {0, 5}], 'P': [{0, 9}, {8, 7}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that squared gets overwritten. You can use this if you want a list as result:

```
squared = []
for i in dic['R']:
   squared.append([j ** 2 for j in i])
```